# Checking if an array contains an int with recursion and certain limitations

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

i was given the following problem: create a recursive method that checks if a given array contains a given value. This should be done by splitting the array in two halfes and therfore requires two recursive calls.

The problem for me is that the method head doesnt contain any specifieds index range, that can be altered with recursion, so that every value in the array is searched. I've now tried to just fix the index that is being compared to the value as 0 and continue to split up the array in halfes, so that every value in the array has the index 0 at some point. It doesn't work however and i don't understand why. If anyone could give me a clue as to what i'm doing wrong, that would be helpful, as I'm still very new to java.

My limitations are as follows: no altering of the method head, no global variables, no loops, only classes allowed are: String, Array, Math, Integer.

Example:

`int[] array = {2, 4, 7, 10, -10, 4, 0, 0, 27, 11, 4, 6};`

`System.out.println(containsValue(array4, 11));`
This should be true, in my code it is however false.

Code:

```
private static boolean containsValue(int[] workArray, int value) {

    int count = 0;
    boolean hasValue;

    if (workArray.length > 1) {
        int[] firstHalfArray = Arrays.copyOfRange(workArray, 0, (workArray.length / 2) - 1);
        if (firstHalfArray[count] == value) {
            hasValue = true;
            return containsValue(firstHalfArray, value) || hasValue;
        }
    }

    if (workArray.length > 1) {
        int[] secondHalfArray = Arrays.copyOfRange(workArray, 6, workArray.length - 1);
        if (secondHalfArray[count] == value) {
            hasValue = true;
            return containsValue(secondHalfArray, value) || hasValue;
        }

    }

    return false;

}


public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] array4 = {2, 4, 7, 10, -10, 4, 0, 0, 27, 11, 4, 6};
    System.out.println(containsValue(array4, 11));
    System.out.println(containsValue(array4, 2));
    System.out.println(containsValue(array4, 25));
    System.out.println(containsValue(array4, 0));
    System.out.println(containsValue(array4, 14));
    System.out.println(containsValue(array4, 6));
}
```

Thanks in advance

Update: I have tuned and adjusted my code. My base case was horribly wrong, thanks for that. The rest of it still isnt working the way i want it to, even though for my the recursion is correctly implemented (I still continue to split it in half until the base case is reached (workArray.lenght == 1) and the check if that single int in the array is equal to value. What am I still doing wrong?

```
private static boolean containsValue(int[] workArray, int value) {

        int count = 0;

        if (workArray.length > 1) {
            int[] firstHalfArray = Arrays.copyOfRange(workArray, 0, (workArray.length / 2));
            return containsValue(firstHalfArray, value);
        }

        if (workArray.length > 1) {
            int[] secondHalfArray = Arrays.copyOfRange(workArray, workArray/2, workArray.length - 1);
            return containsValue(secondHalfArray, value);
        }

        if (workArray[count] == value) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
```

Comment: *The problem for me is that the method head doesnt contain any specifieds index range, that can be altered with recursion*: then create another recursive method, and call that other method with 0, array.length as arguments. Your method has an obvious bug: if the array only has one element, it always returns false.

Comment: thats not allowed either..

Comment: The idea of recursive subdivision is to check the base case to see if you can solve it trivially. Here look for a list of 1 element and return that. Otherwise split the array in 2 and recur on each half (be careful a half doesn't have length 0). For this have a look at List.subList().  This method needs only constant space and time. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList-int-int-

Comment: Again, your base case (an array with only one element), is wrongly implemented: it always returns false. For all the other cases, you should split the array in two and return true if one of the two subarrays contain the number. Your `hasValue` variable shouldn't be there.

Comment: @gurioso agreed, but then a recursive approach is absurd: if multiple copies of the array are done (using hidden loops), you'd better just iterate over the array. I understand that this is just to learn, but the restriction of not being allowed to create a method ruins the point of using recursion.

Comment: I've posted an update where i fixed some things, thank you. Its still not really working, not sure why tho.

Comment: If the array isn’t sorted, there’s no point in a recursive solution; just check each element from the first to last. If it is sorted, you would use a [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm), which seems to be what is being asked of you. Are you sure the array isn’t supposed to be sorted?

Comment: No its supposed to be random and i have to use recursion, as its a requirement for this problem.

Comment: Now you're handling the non-base case incorrectly. You should split the array in two and return true if one of the two subarrays contain the number. Currently, you only check the first sub-array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand

- why you need this recursion here at all
- why you copy the array subsets ... it is better to keep search range in method parameters containsValue(int[] workArray, int value, int startindex, int endidex)
- last attribute in copyOfRange is end index but exclusively

  ```
  private static boolean containsValue(int[] workArray, int value) {

      if (workArray.length == 0) return false;
      if (workArray[0] == value) return true;
      if (workArray.length == 1) return false;

      int middle = workArray.length / 2;

      int[] firstHalfArray = Arrays.copyOfRange(workArray, 0, middle);
      if(containsValue(firstHalfArray, value)) return true;
      int[] secondHalfArray = Arrays.copyOfRange(workArray, middle, workArray.length);
      return containsValue(secondHalfArray, value);

  }
  ```

Comment: Using recursion is required on this one, as per specifiction of this task. Thank your for the solution